# How to calculate number of weeks between two ISO dates

Tags: python, date-difference

I am reading excel files line by line where I have in one column ISO year_week_start : 2020_53 and in second ISO year_week_end : 2021_01

I am looking how to get distance between these two strings

```
2021_01 - 2020_53 => 1
2020_40 - 2020_30 => 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```py
from datetime import date

def convert(value):
    (year, week) = [int(x) for x in value.split('_')]
    result = date.fromisocalendar(year, week, 1)
    return result

def distance(date1, date2):
    date1 = convert(date1)
    date2 = convert(date2)
    diff = date1 - date2
    weeks = diff.days / 7
    return weeks

print(distance('2021_01', '2020_53'))
print(distance('2020_40', '2020_30'))
print(distance('2021_01', '1991_01'))
```

**Output**

```
1.0
10.0
1566.0
```

Comment: Yes its exactly thx